# N-tree, shared_ptr and "cannot declare field "tnode::data" to be of abstract type Figure

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, weak-ptr

I recently began to learn object oriented programming and now I'm faced with the problem of changing program with usual pointers to program with shared_ptr.
I try to create a program with a container (n-tree), which contains twi types of figures: Hexagons and Rhombuses. And I must also use shared_ptr. 
The first question is:
For example, I have a function, that adds an element to n-tree:

```
tnode *add(tnode **node, const Figure figure) {
tnode *pnext = NULL;
tnode *p = (tnode *)malloc(sizeof(tnode));
p->data = rhombus;
p->parent = NULL;
p->prev = NULL;
p->next = NULL;
p->child = NULL;
if (*node == NULL)
    *node = p;
else if ((*node)->child == NULL) {
    p->parent = *node;
    (*node)->child = p;
} else {
    pnext = (*node)->child;
    while (pnext->next != NULL)
        pnext = pnext->next;
    p->parent = *node;
    p->prev = pnext;
    pnext->next = p;
}
return p;
}
```

...or destroys the tree:

```
void destroy(tnode **node) {


if (*node == NULL)
    return;
if ((*node)->next != NULL)
    destroy(&(*node)->next);
if ((*node)->child != NULL)
    destroy(&(*node)->child);
free(*node);
*node = NULL;
}
```

How it will look with std::shared_ptr?
And the second problem is that compilator doesn't see that Figure is a parent class for other two figures:

Figure.h

```
    class Figure {
public:
    virtual bool operator==(const Figure& right);
    virtual &Figure::operator=(const Figure& right);
    virtual double Square() = 0;
    virtual void Print() = 0;
    virtual ~Figure(){}
};
```

Hexagon.h

```
#include "Figure.h"

class Hexagon : public Figure{
public:
Hexagon();
Hexagon(std::istream &is);
Hexagon(float side);
Hexagon(const Hexagon& orig);

bool operator==(const Hexagon& right);
Hexagon& operator=(const Hexagon& right);

double Square() override;
void   Print() override;

virtual ~Hexagon();
//private:
int side;
};
```

Rhombus.h

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include "Figure.h"

class Rhombus : public Figure{
Rhombus();
Rhombus(std::istream &is);
Rhombus(int side, float angle);
Rhombus(const Rhombus& orig);

bool operator==(const Rhombus& right);
double Square();// override;

Rhombus& operator=(const Rhombus& right);

virtual ~Rhombus();
//private:
int side;
float angle;
};
```

In functions "add" and "destroy" (where a parameter is A Figure) compiler also writes
"cannot declare field figure to be of abstract type Figure"

And the last question. As I understand, in a structure of N-Tree one part of structure "ownes" some others, so wear_ptr are needed. Is there a mistake?

```
struct tnode {
Figure data;
std::weak_ptr<tnode>parent;
std::weak_ptr<tnode>prev;
std::shared_ptr<tnode>next;
std::shared_ptr<tnode>child;
~tnode();
};
```

So, could you say me, where I am wrong and how to solve the problem.

Comment: This heavy use of pointers does **not** look like C++ or OOP.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't use the C++ `new` and `delete` operators? Because if you use `malloc` and `free` the constructors and destructor won't actually be called, and that might lead to bad things.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg is that right in "add":  `std::shared_ptr<tnode>p = new tnode;`?

Answer (score 0):

In the `tnode` structure you declare an *instance* of the `Figure` class, which can't be done since it's abstract. You need to use a pointer instead.

Same thing with the `add` function, you pass a `Figure` instance by value which can't be done since it's abstract.

Comment: I need everywhere use `Figure *figure` in functions?
And in a structure `Figure *data`?

Comment: @MichaelPister Yes, you can never have an instance of an abstract class, which includes things like passing by value.